# Deleting Named Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a macro that takes a sheet in the active workbook and copies it to a new workbook, and then attempts to delete the named ranges before saving. All iterations of deleting the named ranges that I have attempted have failed with the same error:

> [image: Delete named ranges error]

Here is the code that I have tried, which is the most commonly suggested code I could find:

```
Dim nName As Name
For Each nName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names
    nName.Delete
Next
```

Comment: This code worked perfectly for me regardless of whether the name is scoped to Workbook or Worksheet. Which line in this code is raising the error? Nothing in this code *should* be raising that error, is there more code which is failing elsewhere?

Comment: It's super similar - but does [this code](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=219) do the trick? It ignores the errors, which I suppose you could do in your sub as well. Also, does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25394013/4650297) provide any insight?  Also, are you *sure* the `ActiveWorkbook` is the one you're expecting?

Comment: I just copy and pasted your code into a blank sub and it removed all the names from my Name Manager. Have you tried stepping through the code with F8?

Comment: This code also works whether one Named Range refers to another named range which is deleted first... (e.g., "name2 refers to name1", and then delete "name1", etc.)

Comment: what is the output of: `Dim nName As Name //
    For Each nName In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Names //
        MsgBox (nName.Name) //
    Next` // (Where "//" indicates a line brake since comments are only one line)

Comment: The line causing the error is: `nName.Delete`

Comment: Your use of `Application` and `Next` instead of `Next rName` indicate to me that you are running this in [vbscript], not [excel-vba]. On hte flip side, `Dim nName As Name` indicates [excel-vba]. Could you confirm the compiler platform?

Comment: So removing the `Application.` per @Jeeped and adding the `On Error` suggestions from @BruceWayne worked. Appreciate the help guys!

Also, I apparently suck at writing comments, so thanks for baring with me!

Comment: @Jeeped It is possible to use `Application`, and `Next` without a label with VBA. In fact, the only way using `Application` would indicate VBScript is if there is a variable named `Application`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz - Yes, it is. However, they are more commonly used in [vbscript] hence my comments stated that they were an **indication** that may require clarification and not an absolute.

Answer (score 3):

> <sup>Too long for a comment; I will delete if this does not resolve the situation.</sup>

When you created the defined names in the workbook, you may have unintentionally used a reserved word or duplicated the name of a shape or other object. The following may help identify the defined name by its index, not the object itself.

```
do while cbool(activeWorkbook.names.count)
    activeWorkbook.Names(1).Delete
loop
```

I believe that both the `.Count` and index of the [Workbook.Names collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.names.aspx) are 1-based.